# Mimekit or Mailkit or Mail which can allow different from and return path values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, mailkit, mimekit

Hello I am trying to use any of the libraries Mimekit, Mailkit of net mail to achieve different from and return path emails mainly to help in non delivery reports

Example : I want to send the emails via noreply@domain.com but in case if the emails fail to deliver I want the bounce or delivery notifications to he sent to a specific email joe@domain.com

I was able to use the mail.Sender but it adds the on behalf of logic to the message which I don’t want. Anyone has achieved what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have 100% control over the headers when using MimeKit and MailKit except for whatever the SMTP server itself decides to add or override.